# No logro extraer datos de una bd a un select en html y php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Listado de Clientes por Distrito

```
        <h3>Listado de Clientes Por Distrito</h3>
        <img src="banner_clientes.png" width="700" height="210"/>

    </header>

    <?php 
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

error_reporting(E_ALL);
                //error_reporting(0);
                include('conecta.php');
                include('captura.php');
         ?>

```
     <form action="ListCliDist.php" method="POST">
        <table border="0" width="700" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Seleccione Su Distrito</td>
                <td><select name="selDistrito">
                    <?php 
                            $rs=$cn -> query( "SELECT DISTINCT C.ID_DISTRITO, D.DESCRIPCION FROM CLIENTE C INNER JOIN DISTRITO D ON C.ID_DISTRITO = D.ID_DISTRITO");


                        $n = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
                            for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
                                $codigo=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs, $i, 0);
                                $distrito=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs, $i, 1);
                                echo "<option value='".$codigo."'>"
                                                                    .$distrito."</option>";
                            }

                     ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="btnListar" value="LISTAR"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php 
                $codigo=getDistrito();
                $consulta=mysqli_query($cn, "select descripcion from distrito where id_distrito='$codigo'");
                $distrito=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta,0,1);

                //Implementando la consulta
                $sql="SELECT c.id_cliente, CONCAT(c.nombres,'',c.paterno,'',c.materno),c.fono,d.descripcion FROM CLIENTE INNER JOIN distrito  on c.id_distrito=d.id_distrito where c.id_distrito='$codigo'";
                //Realizando la consulta en base al distrito seleccionado
                $rsC=mysqli_query($cn,$sql);
                //Determinar el total de clientes
                $total=mysqli_num_rows($rsC);
         ?>
         <p id="centrado">Clientes del Distrito: <?php echo $distrito; ?></p>
         <table border="0" width=700 cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
            <tr>
                <th>CODIGO</th>
                <th>CLIENTE</th>
                <th>TELEFONO</th>
                <th>DISTRITO</th>
            </tr>   
            <?php for ($i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) { 
             ?>
             <tr>
                <td><?php echo mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsC, $i, 0) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsC, $i, 1) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsC, $i, 2) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsC, $i, 3) ?></td>
             </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <th>TOTAL</th>
                <th><?php $total ?></th>
            </tr>
         </table>
        </form>
     </section>
        <footer> 
                <h5>Todos Los Derechos Reservados @2019</h5>

        </footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código no es el mejor que digamos, hay huecos de seguridad, sintaxis y consumo de CPU, es algo que puedes mejorar, ahora, si tu único problema es llenar el `<select>` aquí te dejo un código documentado y corregido

```
<?php 
//Intenta nombrar siempre tus tuplas con alias, para que al momento de recoger sea más fácil
$query  = "SELECT DISTINCT (C.ID_DISTRITO) AS 'CODE', 
          D.DESCRIPCION as 'NAME' FROM CLIENTE C 
          INNER JOIN DISTRITO D 
          ON C.ID_DISTRITO = D.ID_DISTRITO";

$result =  $cn->query( $query );

//Primero valida que no haya un error a nivel de query
if( !$result ){
  echo '<option selected disabled>Ocurrió un error en el servidor</option>';

}else{

  //Ahora valida que hayan registros en la base de datos
  if( mysqli_num_rows($result) <= 0 ){
    echo '<option selected disabled>No hay Distritos disponibles</option>';
  }

  //Si todo está bien entonces barre el resultado con un while, no con un for
  else{

    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
      $codigo   = $row['CODE'];
      $distrito = $row['NAME'];
      echo "<option value='" . $codigo . "'>" . $distrito . "</option>";
    }
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Si. Estoy estudiando. No es algo para llevar a producción. Muy agradecido con su ayuda.